# Drawing balls from $n$ numbered balls $k+1$ times with replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Consider:

$E_j$: the maximum of the values obtained on $k+1$ draws is $j$, $j=1,\ldots…,n$,

$F_j$: all the draws are done on $\{1,\ldots,j\}$, $j=1,\ldots,n$

$F_0 = \emptyset$.

1. Calculate P($E_j$)

I tried to divide the problem in many cases where $j=1,2,\ldots,n$.
With $j=1$, we have $|E_1| = k+1$ because when $1$ is the maximum value observed, we draw only $1$ ball. After $k+1$ times, there are $k+1$ possibilities where $E_1$ can be performed. 
With the same reason,

$$
|E_n| = (k+1) 2^{n-1}.
$$

Then

$$
|E_j| = (k+1) (1+4+8+...+2^{n-1}).
$$

We do have P($E_j$) = |$E_j$| / |$S$| = $(k+1) (1+4+8+...+2^{n-1})$ / $(1^{k+1} + 2^{k+1}+\ldots+n^{k+1})$

So, my question is: Is there any relation between $Ej$ and $S$? 
And can you guys double-check my answer for this?

2. Calculate P($F_j$)

I can't reach the idea. But If I'm not wrong, for example, $F_2$ is considered as the event where we draw just 2 balls: number 1 and number 2??

Please give me some instructions. Ty so much!!!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that $n,k$ are fixed? And $E_{j}$ is an event such that in $k+1$ draws we draw balls with numbers from set $\{1,...,j\}$ and there is at least $1$ ball with $j$ - number?

Comment: Yes,$n$ and $k$ are all fixed. Actually, $E_j$ is an event such that in $k+1$ draws, we draw balls numbered $1,2,...,n$ and the maximum value observed is $j$

Comment: "After $k+1$ times, there are $k+1$ possibilities where $E_1$ can be performed."  I don't see that (or else I'm misinterpreting the problem).  The only way you can get $E_1$ is if you draw ball $1$ each of the $k+1$ draws.  How do you get $k+1$ ways to do that?

Comment: Oh yes, I think it's me who misunderstood the problem. So if I wanna get $E2$, are there 2 ways? The first one is if I draw ball 2 each of the $k+1$ draws, and we can also get $E2$ if we draw ball 1 and ball 2 ?

Comment: The order in which we drew the balls matters?